# Can I add new text field in TFS pending changes section to add Jira ticket?

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, jira

[pending changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ZKz.png)

Can I add new field be added into pending changes section like Jira ID to keep track of each check-in made for which Jira ticket?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in VS or TFS directly to achieve it. You may need to use 3rd-party  extension or write a extension by yourself.

You can try [this tool](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pigsty.jira.plugin.usetfs/server/overview) which Integrate Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio with JIRA.